# Javascript AJAX failing when put in to a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, mobile-safari

I've written the following code to get JSON data with a POST request.

```
    $.post("http://example.com/songs/search_api/index.php",
      "data[Song][keyword]=Stereophonics",
      function(data){
        /*$("#results").append(data);*/
        alert("test");

        var songdata = JSON.parse(data);

        //$("#results").empty();

        var i = 0;

        for (i=0;i<=songdata.total;i++)
        {
            //alert(i);

            var songhtml = "<ul><li><img src=\"" + songdata.data[i].artwork + "\" /></li><li>" + songdata.data[i].title + "</li><li>" + songdata.data[i].artist + "</li><li>" + songdata.data[i].length + "</li><li>" + songdata.data[i].listen + "</li></ul>";
            //alert(songhtml);
            $("#results").append(songhtml);

        }
        //var objectasstring = concatObject(songdata);
        //alert(objectasstring + "\n\n" + songdata);
      }
    );
```

The problem is as soon as I put in a function (this works without the above code) the function fails to run;

```
function postRequest() {

alert("hello??");

}
```

This is for mobile Safari on the iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Are you putting the function inside postRequest and calling postRequest on the page?

Comment: Exactly. I put the $.post in to the postRequest function and submit this form;

        <form>
         <img src="logo.jpg" /><br />
       <input type="text" id="searchField" value="Query" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="postRequest()" />
     
      </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! My problem? The form. I was using a form so the page was being refreshed when the function was run.